# replace specific letters in a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace some specific letters with other for example :

> "This is an sample text for demonstration"

i need to replace

> "tion" with "ting"

I have tried like these,

> (1)Regex space=new Regex(@"\b[a-zA-z]tion\b");
>     space.Replace(string,"ting");
>
> (2)Regex.Replace(nonTagText, @"(\d+|.| )tion(\d+|.| )", "$1ting$2");

but its not useful .

can anyone tell suitable regex please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use string.Replace()?

Comment: It seems you have more requirements than just any string "tion" with "ting". What circumstances should it be replaced or not replaced? Examples of strings that you want replaced and other examples where it shouldn't be replaced is usually helpful.

Comment: The answer to your literal question is `Regex.Replace("This is an sample text for demonstration", "tion", "ting")` but I don't know how helpful that is

Comment: There is no need for Regex here.
string str = "This is ....... demonstration";
str = str.Replace("tion","ting");

Comment: thanks for your response guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could be like this:

```
 string mystring = "This is an sample text for demonstration";
            Regex space = new Regex(@"(?<=\w)+tion");
            string result = space.Replace(mystring, "ting");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

i find alternate way , thanks for your response guys.

```
String sourcestring = "This is alternate answer for demonstration";
String matchpattern = @"tion";
String replacementpattern = @"ting";              
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sourcestring,matchpattern,replacementpattern));
```

Comment: But this is just a plain string.Replace